# How to extract multiple images from video by timestamps with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I can extract one image from a video like below.

```
ffmpeg -ss <timestamp> -i <input_path> -frames:v 1 <output_path>
```

But I need to extract 100 or 1000 images from a video.
I can just do this by running the command above multiple times, but I want to do this in a more efficient way.

Comment: Have a look here... https://superuser.com/a/1330042